# Android Studio (Kotlin) buttons unresponsive after switching tabs

Tags: android, android-studio, button, kotlin

I have three tabs in my Android app. Each tab is a different "mini-game" and each has it's own button to start the mini-game.

The mini-games are started with a button that has an onClick function.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/game1button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="startGame1"
    android:text="@string/game_1_desc"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_home"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.85"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_rounded"
    android:padding="5dp"
    />
```

Each xml layout has it's own button for it's own game. This works perfectly fine. The button works an infinite amount of times while you are on that tab.

The problem is - If you click the button once. Go to a different tab, then come back and click it again... the button does nothing and is unresponsive. This only happens if the button has been clicked once previously.

I tried setting debug messages to check if the functions are being called and they aren't at all, the button literally does nothing. I am very confused.

Comment: What does the buttons do? Post the button onClick snippet

Comment: Also inside what lifecycle method are you setting the listener for the button?